# How to set JDropDown submenu with in a different location

Tags: java, selenium

I have created a JDropDown menu. I need a submenu in a different place on JFrame, basically, it's another JDropDown menu. and It shows with a condition like No dropdown menu should show at the start but after a click on any dropdown option the other dropdown menu shows, and options of that 2nd dropdown based on the main dropdown.

I have tried that code. It shows 2nd dropdown on click on any option of 1st dropdown. but If I add one more same thing with cb.setSelectedIndex(1) it can't work.

```java
String[] choices = {"Redeem","Prepaid", "FRC","Offices","Individual Bags","Gift Subscription","E-Gift Card","My Account","Wp-Admin","Shipstaion","Any date changes"}; 
final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(choices); cb.setBounds(134,200, 170,30); 
cb.setSelectedIndex(0);
cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
         try { 
            String[ ] choices1 = {"Redeem Remaining & Redeem Gift Card","Redeem of Tasting Kit Sub","US & NON-US Redeem","Manually Created Vouchers"}; 
            final JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox(choices1);
            cb1.setBounds(100,250, 250,30); 
            JF.add(cb1); 
         } catch (Exception e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); } 
     } 
});
```

expected result should be 2nd dropdown options shows based on the main dropdown option.